# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a React app with below dependencies:

```
"react": "~17.0.0",
"react-dom": "~17.0.0",
```

In my `src/index.js`, I have:

```
import('./bootstrap');
export { };
```

In `src/bootstrap.jsx`, I have:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.render(container);

root.render(<App />);
```

In `public/index.html`, I already have a div with id "root" as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dark">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo64.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#161616" />
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="my-host-ui"
  />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <title>my-host-ui</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The build works and I am able to start the app, but I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

From what I read, it is mostly because of the DOM element missing in `index.html`, but in this case, I already have the DOM element with id "root".

I have replaced this code from an upgraded project (on React v18), which has the code as below

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.render(container);

root.render(<BootstrapApp />);
```

Comment: How do you load *src/index.js*?

Comment: I don't explicitly load index.js anywhere...I guess, it gets invoked automatically on startup

Comment: By what automatism, then? Please post the entire html and your build/dev tooling setup

Comment: I have added my index.html to the OP

Comment: Apart from that, it is a standard React app (on v17) and I am using craco with module federation...Please let me know what other specific thing you need me to add

Comment: `const root = ReactDOM.render(container);` followed by `root.render(<BootstrapApp />);` doesn't make sense. The first call should be to [`createRoot`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#createroot), not `render`. (I don't know that that's the problem, but it's definitely **a** problem.) (Even if you were doing this the old v16 way, you still wouldn't have the second call. But you're using v17, so you want `createRoot`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I am on React v 17 and not on v18...I guess createRoot is not supported in v17

Comment: @copenndthagen - Sorry, misremembered versions. But even on v17 and earlier, that isn't how you do it as far as I know. You just do `ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"));` Docs: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

Comment: https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#updates-to-client-rendering-apis - this changed from 17 to 18, but what you show isn't quite either of them. `ReactDOM.render` takes the element _then_ the container, you're passing only one argument (the container, but as if it was the element) so it's getting `undefined` (which indeed isn't a DOM element) where it expected the container.

Comment: T.J. Crowder is correct. You are invoking multiple render method. You need to invoke it on ReactDOM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.render(container); // <====

root.render(<BootstrapApp />); // (This is also incorrect)
```

Live example of the error:

```js
const BootstrapApp = () => {
    return <div>App</div>;
};

try {
    const container = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = ReactDOM.render(container);

    root.render(<BootstrapApp />);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That isn't how you bootstrap a React app with v17, it's like a cross between the old v17 and earlier way and the v18+ way. You get the error because you're not passing a second argument to `ReactDOM.render`, so it gets `undefined`, so you get the error.

The correct v17 and earlier way is:

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, container);
```

or simply:

```
ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Live example:

```js
const BootstrapApp = () => {
    return <div>App</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

For completeness, the correct v18+ way is:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
// ...
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<BootstrapApp />);
```

or simply:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
// ...
createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<BootstrapApp />);
```

Live example:

```js
const BootstrapApp = () => {
    return <div>App</div>;
};

// Note: Can't use `import` version, so we use `ReactDOM` here
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<BootstrapApp />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```